# Why is my value null when calling superclass method from subclass?

Tags: java, object, subclass, superclass

I'm working with Java and Android Studio IDE. I am trying to call a method in a parent class from it's sub class. I have written a small test routine but I am only getting a null result.

In my main project I have Parent and Child Objects/Classes and I would like to get a value from the the Parent Object/Class called from the SubClass/Object. (House Object consists of Wall Objects and my Wall Object is trying to get the "Wall Type" specified within the House Class. But below is a small example of what I am working with.

I have tried searching for this issue, but reading other people's code a lot of times just makes this issue more confusing for me. I must be misunderstanding how this is supposed to work.

I have tried rewriting how I fetch the data, either by calling then super.getMethod() or Overriding the Parent's method. I have also played with my variables/methods being public/private and protected but have achieved nothing.

My Parent Class:

```
public class Parent {
    protected String myName;
    protected Child parentsChild;

    public Parent() {}

    public Parent (String myName, Child parentsChild) {
        this.myName = myName;
        this.parentsChild = parentsChild;
    }

    public String getMyName() {
        return this.myName;
    }

    public void setMyName(String myName) {
        this.myName = myName;
    }

    public Child getParentsChild() {
        return this.parentsChild;
    }

    public void setParentsChild(Child parentsChild) {
        this.parentsChild = parentsChild;
    }
}
```

My Child Class:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    String childName;

    public Child() {

    }

    public Child(String childName) {
        this.childName = childName;
    }

    public String getChildName() {
        return childName;
    }

    public void setChildName(String childName) {
        this.childName = childName;
    }

    public String getParentName() {
        return super.getMyName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getMyName() {
        return super.getMyName();
    }
}
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Child child = new Child("Logan");

        Parent parent = new Parent("Karrie", child);

        System.out.println("Parent: My name is " + parent.getMyName());
        System.out.println("Child: My parent's name is " + child.getParentName());
        System.out.println("@Override-> Child: My Parent's name is " + child.getMyName());
    }
}
```

I am hoping to retrieve the Parent's name as I passed it when constructing the class Parent with "Karrie". Instead I only get "null". What a poor child! :-(

Here is my log:

```
2019-10-17 20:25:36.594 27040-27040/com.example.android.superclassinheritancetesting I/System.out: Parent: My name is Karrie
2019-10-17 20:25:36.594 27040-27040/com.example.android.superclassinheritancetesting I/System.out: Child: My parent's name is null
2019-10-17 20:25:36.594 27040-27040/com.example.android.superclassinheritancetesting I/System.out: @Override-> Child: My Parent's name is null
```

Thank you kindly for any help! :]

Comment: Your Child constructors never call the super constructor that passes in the parent's name, nor do you explicitly set the parent's name anywhere in onCreate. No surprise here.

Comment: I'd try debugging--the answer is fairly clear. You extend parent (ignoring that the subtyping makes no sense here) but you never set myName. This would be better represented as a single class, with a list of children, ask if which are simply a Person.

Comment: Well, in my real code I have a "wall class/object" to which I specify a "frametype" (string). I then have  a "wall section class/object" (which has wall panels as an additional subclass but irrelevant for this) which is extended from the wall class. When I get to calculating the price (instead of each wall section having it's own frame type) I'm just trying to get the wall frame type from the parent "wall". The relationship is similar as in my code here. (It's an ArrayList of various wallsections). I thought I'm setting the name through the default constructor here? Is that not the case?

Comment: Also: The parent here clearly know it's own name, but when trying to call that very same method from the child/sub class, I get null returned. As I stated, I must fundamentally misunderstand how this works, but a pointer in the right direction is greatly appreciated. In other words. Is there a way for my child object/class to retrieve the name of the parent?! Edit: The code above produces the same exact result as my real code which is like 1500 lines long. Also StackOverflow asks me to reduce my code to the minimum possible to reproduce the issue I have.

Comment: "The parent here clearly know it's own name"??? the parent will only get what is passed into it, no more and no less. If your real code is reflective of this code, then please re-read my first comment again to see why your assumption above is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Why does `Child` extend `Parent`? If anything it should be the other way around. Parents are always someone's child, but children may never become parents at all.

Comment: By saying "the parent knows it's own name" I simply mean that I can simply call the getMyName method from the parent class and it produces the proper value. (as shown in the log) When trying to call that same method from the child class, I get null. (as shown in the log) I am so lost right now, been a long day.

Comment: You get null because you never set it otherwise, as @HovercraftFullOfEels has told you several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, inheritance might not be the right approach in this case.

You can define a single `Node` class to model the relationship.

```
class Node {

  String name;
  Node parent;

  public Node(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Node(String name, Node parent) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  public String getParentName() {
    return this.parent != null ? this.parent.name : null;
  }

}
```

Then in your client code:

```
Node parent = new Node("ParentName");
Node child = new Node("ChildName", parent)
System.out.println(child.getParentName());
```

Comment: Oh boy, then I  might be entirely off in the wrong direction. I have a dozen different Classes that build on top of each other in this fashion. I am trying to model a Screen Enclosure, which in my logic is the parent. Then the ScreenEnclosure Class has "Wall and Roof Classes" as children (and some other one's), and in return, each of those have "Roof and Wall Sections" as children and ultimately I have a "Screen Panel Class" which defines measurements as width, height, screen type, etc. Walls consist of x Wall Sections, which consists of x Screen Panels .

Comment: It seems like the relationships you are describing are `has-a` rather than `is-a`.  If if a _Wall_ is not really a kind of _ScreenEnclosure_ then inheritance will not be helpful while modeling that relationship. I would suggest to review [Java's Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) to determine if inheritance is the right approach for your problem.

Comment: You are right. There is only one instance where I am trying to inherit something in my entire code (thank god) and it appears that it probably doesn't make any sense at all for what I am trying to accomplish.  At first I thought it made sense, but I will need to read up about this subject matter quite a bit more. Only a couple months into this journey so far. Thanks for the help

Comment: I think my real problem is not inheritance, but access from inner classes to outer classes, but I am reading about that right now. (I think I may have confused those things) And yes, I can only reiterate that I have lots to learn still.

Comment: No problem. Good luck! If this answered your original question please consider accepting the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the way you are adding child values in parent.

You need to pass these values through the child class constructor. I suggest to you create other construct in **Parent** where you could receive only **myName** attribute and in **Child** class you pass myName (parentName) to Parent using super, like you are using in your get methods. Can do as follows:

Add (or change) a new construct in **Parent**:

```
public Parent (String myName) {
   this.myName = myName;
}
```

And in **Child**:

```
public Child(String childName, String parentName) {
    super(parentName)
    this.childName = childName;
}
```

And in **onCreate** method you just need create a child instance, like this:

```
Child child = new Child("Logan", "Karrie");
```

In this way, the Parent class doesn't need to know and contain the Child class variable.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the use of inheritance here is probably not the right way to implement your desired functionality.  The reference to the java tutorials will definitely help you understand inheritance and differentiate it from composition or aggregation. Your example uses both at the same time, making it very difficult to grasp the concepts as a beginner. If you are still interested in a hierarchical relationship (parent/child, not super/sub class), take a look at this interface and its implementations from the JDK. There are methods to get parent and get child objects in the hierarchy.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html

Comment: Absolutely. I misunderstood the entire concept. Now after reading up about it I was generally more interested in being able to access an outer class method from an inner class or object. I have actually no requirement to use class inheritance with what I was trying to do. After getting some good pointers from other members, I realized what I needed to do. :-) I'll check that out.Thanks!! I'm just thrilled to keep learning new ways and concepts and moving forward.